# Difference between "close up" and "close down"

Tags: verbs

What is the difference between *close up* and *close down*? They look like completely different verbs because of the contrast between the words *up* and *down*, but they have similar meanings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many idiomatic usages where one word or the other is normally used, but the other would be understood to convey the same meaning. You normally *close up a gap*, or *close down a mine*, for instance.

You **close up** a shop, for example, at the end of every day's trading (then next morning you might *open up* again). If you **close down** the shop, the implication is the business is being "wound up", and will not re-open unless someone buys it off you and starts trading afresh.

Normally, *close up a debate* means to be the last speaker, summarising all that's been said on both sides of the issue. On the other hand, if you *close down the debate*, that means you (the chairman, for example) unilaterally end the debate by formally ruling out any further discussion.

TL;DR: Where there's a distinction, *close down* implies something more "final" than "close up".

Comment: Aside: You could also say business is being "wound down".  I once picked corn for a farmer who would say "wind it up!" and meant "work faster!" (as in *winding* a watch or music box).  You can imagine our disappointment when we found this out.

Comment: I would say that **close up** is not necessarily more "final"; instead, I would say it is "complete normally" where **close down** means "terminated".

Comment: If you "wind down" a business, it might still exist indefinitely in a smaller form, so it's a different meaning from "wind up". As when you apply it to a person, who might "wind down" with relaxing music, or be "wound up" by a stressful situation. But if I'd been your farmer, I'd have said *"Crank it up!"*

Comment: And "final" means "terminal", so I don't see what you're getting at there.

Comment: Re: final vs. terminal -- "terminated" is different from "terminal", isn't it?  At least in the sense of being *cut off* as opposed to simply *the end*.

Comment: I disagree. I think if you say, "We had to close up shop," you mean you went out of business. You wouldn't say "We had to close *down* shop."

Comment: @Robusto: That's just a peculiar idiomatic usage. If you say "We had to close up *the* shop" it probably means you shut temporarily (riots, staff absence, etc.) But if you just "close up shop" it's more likely a metaphoric usage not involving a standard bricks-and-mortar retail establishment at all - perhaps just a temporary affair selling (stolen) goods off the back of a lorry, for example.

Comment: @Fumble: Well, to be fair, both "close up" and "close down" are idiomatic usages.

Comment: @Robusto: Indeed. And I doubt the semantic distinction I've made in respect of "shop" applies universally either. Per last para of my answer, they're only tendencies that *might* enable distinctions. It would be an unwise speaker who relied on the choice of *up* or *down* to convey which one he meant in any context where the difference was crucial and not otherwise provided by context.

Comment: Turn the air up..  Does that mean make the room cooler or hotter?

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain: I think that just depends on context. I'd expect it to always mean "increase the amount of energy being used by the internal climate control system", which would reduce temperature if it was a/c trying to cool you in summer, or increase it if we're talking about c/h in winter. But personally I'd either say *aircon* or *heating* anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I have read all and I will do my best to clarify my thoughts about the difference

Comment: @kiraz: As Robusto and myself have indicated, *close up* and *close down* are very much idiomatic usages. So I do not think you should read to much into anything said here because it won't really embody any "deep underlying principle" governing how the different words are used. To a considerable extent these are simply random choices, where the one that happens to be heard most often simply tends to get repeated more.